# Spontaneity of endothermic reactions

Tags: heat, entropy

I see the Gibbs Free Energy explanation everywhere, but is there an *intuitive* explanation of how endothermic reactions can happen spontaneously?  It seems intuitively reasonable that heat flows from hot to cold, by considering how more energetic molecules impart energy to less energetic molecules.  But how can this intuition be adapted for spontaneous endothermic reactions?

Comment: Are you aware that for closed, isothermic, isobaric systems, $- \dfrac{\Delta G}{T} \le \Delta S_\text{universe}$ ?  // and that for spontaneous processes in isolated systems, $\Delta S \gt 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The spontaneous character of a reaction is not only related to the thermic effet. For example, the reaction of $\ce{NaHCO3}$ on a dilute acidic solution is spontaneous and endothermic. This spontaneity is due to the large entropy increase of the reaction, due to the production of the gas $\ce{CO2}$.

Here the variation of enthalpy is positive. But, as the change of entropy is positive and rather important, the change of free enthalpy in the reaction is negative, and the reaction becomes spontaneous.

Comment: Would it not be more accurate to say that the spontaneous character of a reaction is not *only* related to the thermic effect but depends also on entropic factors?

Comment: Hi Maurice and Buck, thank you for your replies.  I understand how, formulaically, the entropy is an additional factor to the enthalpy.  However, I'm specifically seeking an explanation from an _intuitive_ angle.  That more energetic molecules collide with, and thereby impart energy to, less energetic molecules, seems to give an intuitive explanation as to why heat flows from hot to cold.  What I'm trying to find is how that intuitive explanation needs to be modified to explain the entropic effect.  Thanks and regards.